# Create Duplicate of list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to create a duplicate of this List, I want every content on it to copied to another List with any name. (For filtering purpose)

```
List<FcConstructor> fcContents = [
    FcConstructor(
        questionText: 'Value of Garavitational constant?', answerText: '9.81')
  ];
```

FcConstructor:

```
  String questionText;
  String answerText;
  FcConstructor({this.questionText, this.answerText});
}
```

Tried,(but not working)

```
List<FcConstructor> fg = List.from(fcContents);
```

Comment: Could you give more context? You want the elements inside that list to be copy on another list? Is that list generated by you? Server side?

Comment: Yeah, this list has a add property so it will become large in future and I want to make a copy(Duplicate) of this list(inc future contents) for applying filter.
actually I am a beginner don't have enough idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for a `BuiltList`

https://pub.dev/documentation/built_collection/latest/built_collection/BuiltList-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [spread operator](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/dart-using-triple-dot-spread-operator-examples). It takes the element of the list and adds them to the new list:

```
List<FcConstructor> fcContents = [
FcConstructor(
    questionText: 'Value of Garavitational constant?', answerText: '9.81')
 ];

List<FcConstructor> fg = [...fcContents];
```

It basically copies the element of the fcContents to fg list and they become two different objects with same elements